# double angle formula computations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\cos A = 2/\sqrt5$ $(3\pi/2 < A < 2\pi)$ and $\sin B = 4/5$ $(\pi/2 < B < \pi)$, compute:

$A=\alpha$,

$B=\beta$

a) $\sin(A-B)$

b) $\cos(B/2)$

c) $\tan2A + \tan2B$

d) $\cos2A - \sin4B$

e) $\tan(3A)$

for a) I got $-\sqrt5/5$ with $\sin(A)= -1/\sqrt5$ and $\cos(B)= -3/5$

I do not remember how to do the rest.

Comment: It's rather hard to understand what you wrote. You better use LaTeX for mathematics here and, in the meanwhile, please do drop that awful "alpha, beta" , etc. things and use simply other letters, like w, q or whatever.

Comment: Sorry, I edited to use A and B rather than alpha and beta.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

You have to use the basic trigonometric identities:

$$\sin(A\pm B)=\sin A\cos B\pm\sin B\cos A$$

$$\cos(A\pm B)=\cos A\cos B\mp\sin A\sin B$$

$$\tan(A\pm B)=\frac{\tan A\pm\tan B}{1\mp\tan A\tan B}$$

$$\sin A=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2A}\;,\;\;\text{the sign depending on the angle, for example:}$$

$$\cos A=\frac2{\sqrt5}\;\;,\;\frac{3\pi}2<A<2\pi \;\;\;\text{(and thus we're in the fourth quadrant)}\;\implies$$

$$\implies \sin A=-\sqrt{1-\frac45}=-\frac1{\sqrt5}\;,\;\;etc.$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me more insight on part c and d? There are what I having the most trouble with.

Comment: Put $\;A=B\;$ in the tangent formula: $$\tan 2A=\frac{2\tan A}{1-\tan^2A}$$ so for example in (c) we have $$2\left(\frac{\tan A}{1-\tan^2A}+\frac{\tan B}{1-\tan^2B}\right)$$ but $$\tan A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}=\frac{-\frac1{\sqrt5}}{\frac2{\sqrt5}}=-\frac12\;,\;\;\text{and etc.}$$

Comment: for c I am getting tan2A = -4/5 and tan2B = -24/25. Do I then add these two together? I feel like I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a nice list of trig identities [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).  Given sine or cosines of an angle, the Pythagorean identity yields the absolute value of the other function, and the sign of the function is determined by knowing which quadrant your angle lies in. This is the first step to solving the problem, and something you have already done.

Once you know the sine and cosines of an angle, their ratio yields the tangent. Now, you will need to search for a few different identities: a sum identity, a half angle identity, a few double angle identities (one of which you will need to apply twice) and you will be able to do the first four. For the last one, use the sum identity for tangent twice, once to find $\tan(2A)$, and a second time to find $\tan(2A+A)$.

There are some shortcuts for remembering or deriving some of the identities, but in this particular case, there are no special tricks to applying them. Beyond what you have already done , the problem is entirely looking up and applying formulae.